# Add Claims during the OWIN pipeline with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, owin

I'm trying to explore how it's possible to add additional claims to a User during the OWIN pipeline. 
I know that I can do this at the login stage or at some other points, possibly in the `Application_PostAuthenticate` section in the `Global.asax` since I don't have a `Login` section (it's a Windows Authentication app), but I was wondering if it's possible or even better to do it in the OWIN pipeline.

My idea comes from the fact that OWIN too has a `PostAuthenticate` stage in the pipeline. So I tried this:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var user = context.Authentication.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
        user.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Mr. Tallmaris"));
    }
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

With a break point I can see that the user is the correct one and that the claims are added, but in my View I have something like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
    {
        <li>@claim.Type - @claim.Value</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But my newly added claims are not showing up. Any ideas?

I know that "some" claims need to be added at Application level anyway (roles coming from DB and other things) but I would like to explore adding certain claims straight from the OWIN pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I used this principle in my asp.net application for converting groupsid claims to role claims.

```
app.Use((context, func) => {
  var claimsIdentity = context.Authentication.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
  if (claimsIdentity != null) {
    var claimsToAdd = new List<Claim>();
    //check if we have any groupsid claims, add these as role claims
    foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims) {
      if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.GroupSid) {
        claimsToAdd.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,
          new SecurityIdentifier(claim.Value)
            .Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString()));
      }
    }
    if (claimsToAdd.Count > 0) {
      claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claimsToAdd);
    }
  }
  return func.Invoke();
});
```

This worked for me using Microsoft.Owin v3.0.0.0